# How would you revert data in firestore after cypress afterEach()?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, automation, cypress

I have a Cypress test that's making changes to Firestore backend.

```js
describe('empty spec', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    // run these tests as if in a mobile browser
    // and ensure our responsive UI is correct
    cy.viewport('iphone-x');
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.task('db:seed');
  })

  it('User can update user info data', () => {
    cy.login('testuser@gmail.com', 'parsewood');
    cy.visit('tabs/profile');
    cy.contains('CEO');
    cy.get('textarea').clear();
    cy.get('textarea').type('hello')
    cy.dateSelect();

    cy.selection(0, 'director');
    cy.selection(1, 'executive');
    cy.selection(2, 'principal');
    cy.selection(3, 'engineer');
    cy.get('ion-button').eq(1).click();
  })
})
```

afterEach, I need to reseed the db.  After reading documentation I've tried adding the action in the cypress.config.ts file that would revert the changes in the back end.

Here's one solution I found online:

```js
      on('task', {
        async 'db:seed'() {
          // Send request to backend API to re-seed database with test data
          const { data } = await axios.post(`${testDataApiEndpoint}/seed`)
          return data
        },
```

Here's my attempt to replicate this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import { UserService } from "src/app/services/user.service";
const userService = UserService;

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        async 'db:seed'() {
          this.userService.
        },
      })
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100/'
  },
  includeShadowDom: true
});
```

This fails because I'm not sure on the correct way to import the userService that will make the call to the backend db in order to reset what's been changed.  None of the examples I've seen are reseeding an external db.  Even in the test they're using Axios, but when I try to replicate that it won't work because I need to import Axios.  So how exactly can I reseed the db after a test is executed?

UserService is just a service I created to update the backend.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { getFirestore, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { doc, DocumentData, DocumentSnapshot, setDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { IUserInfo } from '../models/userInfo';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  firestore = getFirestore(getApp());
  db = getFirestore();

  constructor(private alertController: AlertController) { }

  saveProfile(uid: string, email: string, displayName: string): Promise<void> {
    return setDoc(doc(this.db, 'users', uid), {uid, email, displayName});
  }

  getProfile(uid: string): Promise<DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>> {
    return getDoc(doc(this.db, `users`, uid))
  }

  saveUserOptions(userInfo: IUserInfo, uid: string, futureDestinations?: string[]): Promise<void> {
    userInfo.futureDestinations = futureDestinations;
    return setDoc(doc(this.db, 'users', uid), {userInfo}, { merge: true });
  }

  async saved(message: any, header: string): Promise<void> {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      subHeader: `${header}`,
      message: `${message}`,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          role: 'Ok',
          cssClass: 'secondary'
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

[image: After Trying the suggested Answer]

Here's my latest attempt:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import { UserService } from "src/app/services/user.service";
import { AlertController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { Helpers } from "cypress/support/helpers";

const alertController = new AlertController();
const userService = new UserService(alertController);           // create instance of UserService
const helpers = new Helpers();

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        async 'db:seed'() {
          return userService.saveUserOptions(helpers.baseUserData, 'HOF7kWCUdZNTKFdSEGNlyw2');
        },
      })
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100/'
  },
  includeShadowDom: true
});
```

I'm getting this error in Cypress dashboard:
Your configFile is invalid: /Users/bigdaddi/projects/travel/cypress.config.ts

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/bigdaddi/projects/travel/cypress.config.ts

Comment: There's not enough information about user service. Please post code for `src/app/services/user.service`.

Comment: UserService is just a custom service I created to post data to Firebase.  I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

If the seed operation is to set up users, these are the changes I would make

- import `UserService` as relative path (prefix `./`)
- create a new instance of the class to work with
- import a set of users seed data from a fixture
- call the `saveUserOptions` method of userService (you don't need `this` prefix)

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import { UserService } from "./src/app/services/user.service";

import { users } from "./cypress/fixtures/users.json"            // seed data here

const userService = new UserService();           // create instance of UserService

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        async 'db:seed'() {
          userService.saveUserOptions(users, uid)        // call seed method
        },
      })
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100/'
  },
  includeShadowDom: true
});
```

It's a bit rough, since I don't know the application. For instance, the `uid` that is needed to post data to FireStore needs to be added somewhere.

Comment: I'm going to hardcode the UID since it's always the same test user.  However, I can't create the new instance of UserService because that service is injecting an AlertController.  I posted a pic of the error I'm getting.  How do I create the instance and still take into consideration the AlertController inject?

Comment: Yes, that's going to be difficult because Cypress and Angular compile differently. You might try replicating the `setDoc()` call in the task, since that's all you need from the service. But that comes from `@angular/fire/firestore` which might give you similar dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

[Cypress recommends that you clean up state](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks) (or re-seed the database, in this instance) during the `before` or `beforeEach`, and not during `after`/`afterEach`.